# Generate JAVA parser by ANTLR for C++ target

Tags: c++, parsing, antlr

I need to create parser for JAVA code which can be used on C++. I try to use ANTLER to generate parser, but it always generate wrong C++ code which I can't compile. I downloaded antlr-3.5.2-complete.jar from http://www.antlr3.org/download/. After I obtain java grammar Java6Separated from http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html. I modify grammar and update it by inserting

```
options {
  language=Cpp;
}
```

to obtain C++ target. I run in windows console antlr-3.5.2-complete.jar with Java6Lex.g argument (grammar file from Java6Separated zip package) and antler generates Java6Lex and Java6Parse hpp and cpp files. When these files add to my VS2013 project (where I already have an ANTLR runtime hpp because generated hpp-s include them) and compiler reports an error because ANTLR generated Tokens name same that use C++, like CONST, NULL, ... I don't know if I do something wrong or it is a bug in ANTLER.

Do anybody solve this or similar problem? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `NULL` is defined by the standard library. `CONST` is likely being defined by Windows specific headers. This means you'll need to choose identifiers other than `CONST` and `NULL`.

Comment: Yes I understand it bud these "defines" generate ANTLR during generating parser for C++ according to rules. I don't have a choice to modify it. It seems to be a bug in ANTLR

Comment: It's not a bug in ANTLR, the grammar file specifies the identifiers. Modify them there.

Comment: It little helps, bud still there a code mistakes like "C1061: compiler limit : blocks nested too deeply" or "C2065: 'IsFiltered' : undeclared identifier" and some others.

Comment: "C++" doesn't necessarily mean what you think it does.  MS C++, isn't the same C++ as GCC or Clang.  Is there a clear indication ANTLR 3 works with  MS VS C++?   Why don't you ask this question at the ANTLR web site?

Comment: It should work at least with MSVC 2010. C++ target uses templates but AFAIK there are no C++11 features used. But it's hard to tell without seeing any sources nor any errors.